# Regex to find more than one occurrence in GrepWin

Tags: regex, search, find

I want to find more than one occurrence of the tag `h1` in multiples files.

The following regex brings files that has it more than 2 times, which is working great:

```
/(h1.*){2}/
```

However, what if I want to find 2 or more occurrences? (In GrepWin it shows 1 Match, but what to do when I need to see how many matches more than just 1?)

I tried something like `/(h1.*){2+}/`,`/(h1.*){2}+/` or `/(h1.*){2,}/`, but they are not working.

*I am using GrepWin 2.0.15.*

Or do you suggest any other Windows tool to show that?

Comment: Have you tried to make the regex non greedy, like: `(h1.*?){2,}`

Comment: Oh!  That works great. Thanks.

Comment: Do I close the question? Or you'd write an answer with the explaining the regex, especially `?` and its location in the regex :)

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex `(h1.*){2,}` is greedy modify it to become not greedy:

```
(h1.*?){2,}
   __^
```

[Usefull documentation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)